# How to properly stream data from a socket with Java

Tags: java, sockets, csv, tcp

I am attempting stream data over a socket with Java in an attempt to write a Kafka producer. I've written a class to pull the data in but I'm not getting the results I'd expect. I've got it set up so the data is being streamed from a Linux box. The source of the data is a csv file that I'm using the nc utility to stream. The class is running on a Windows 10 machine from Eclipse. When I run the class I see two weird things.

1. The column headers don't get transmitted.
2. I can only run the class once. If I want to run it again, I have to stop nc and restart it.

Below is my code. Am I missing anything? At this point I'm just trying to connect to the socket and pull the data over.

I run nc with the following command:
$ nc -kl 9999 < uber_data.csv

Below is my class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client 
{
static String userInput;

public static void main(String [] args)
{

    try
    {
        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName("servername");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9999);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while ((userInput = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
        }

        input.close();
        socket.close();

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Unknown host exception " + e1.toString());
    }
    catch(IOException e2)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e2.toString());
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e3)
    {
        System.out.println("Illegal Argument Exception " + e3.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e4)
    {
        System.out.println("Other exceptions " + e4.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're throwing away every odd-numbered line. It should be:

```
while ((userInput = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(userInput);
}
```

Secondly, you aren't closing the socket. Use a try-with-resources:

```
try
{
    InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName("servername");
    try (
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9999);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        while ((userInput = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
        }
    }
}
catch (...)
```

Comment: Ok I got my headers back. When I try to do the try block as you suggest, what should i do with: InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName("servername");

When I try to put it in, I get an error InetAddress does not implement AutoCloseable

Comment: Ok nevermind. I put the hostname and portnumber for Socket() as class variables. Still having trouble closing the connection properly though.

Comment: Use nested `try` blocks. Put the one above inside, around the socket-reading code. See edit.

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't even know you could do that. Ok on the closing the connection thing. I still feel like something is wrong. I still can't run this more than once without having to restart nc. It's like it knows it already sent it once and doesn't need to send it again although that's now how I would expect this to work.

Comment: @Kwang-ChunKang states that `nc` won't keep re-sending the file: you have to restart it. That's not a defect in this Java code.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll guess I'll have to write a server to send the file. Another project for another time.

Answer (score 1):

First, each call `readLine()` tries to read line from input stream.
In `userInput = input.readLine()` you read header, but `println(input.readLine())` read body and print in console.

```
while ((userInput = input.readLine()) != null) { 
     System.out.println(userInput); //instead input.readLine()
}
```

Second, I didn't use nc, but I think problem will solve if you will close socket (and reader) in `finally` statement.

Comment: When I try to add a finally block, input and socket aren't recognized.

Comment: Define their above `try` block

Comment: I'm not following.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it would be helpful.

For the first question: you were trying to print `userInput` string. But it's printing the result of another `readline()` call.

For the second: after the file has been transferred, you have to stop and restart `nc`; no matter what you do from your side. It's from `nc` side.

See the [nc documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nc.htm).

Comment: It's not 'my opinion'. It is fact.

Comment: OMG. It's an cultural expression in the asian culture in the modest expression. Anyhow Thank you for advising me. hm..

Comment: In addition, since nc already sent all the stream from it's side,  he have to stop nc and restart it.You can simply try through telnet conneciton. :(

Comment: I didn't know that you edited the text and I accepted your advise and re-edited the answer.hm..... Anyhow Thank you for advising me EJB.